# Spring Cloud Config v3: Are the spring.cloud.config.retry - parameters no longer supported when using spring.config.import: "configserver:"?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I'm trying to upgrade to Spring Cloud 2020.0.0-RC1 and have started to use the new spring.config.import model.

But I can't get the retry mechanism to work anymore.
(as described here: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/blob/master/docs/src/main/asciidoc/spring-cloud-config.adoc#config-client-retry)

I have basically renamed my bootstrap.yml file to appliction.yml and added the line `spring.config.import: "configserver:"`, like:

```
spring.config.import: "configserver:"

spring:
  application.name: product
  cloud.config:
    failFast: true
    retry:
      initialInterval: 3000
      multiplier: 1.3
      maxInterval: 10000
      maxAttempts: 20
```

It works fine to connect to a running config server, but if the config server is not yet started the client no longer retries to connect.

Are the spring.cloud.config.retry - parameters no longer supported when using spring.config.import: "configserver:"?

If not, is there some other way to retry connecting to the config server when using the new spring.config.import model?

Comment: I think that may have slipped through the cracks. I opened an issue here https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/1775. For a workaround, you can add a dependency on `spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap` to restore the old behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the bugfix in https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/1775, it solves the problem!

However, there seems to be a new related issue with corrupted log output. I have reported it in https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/1780.